# How to create hierarchy in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2008

I want to create hierarchy based on dimention build on one tabele. The hierachy is embedded in flat table in this way:

```
id      description    next_id  is_basic

00000   ManagementBoard null    yes

10000   SalesDivision   00000   yes

20000   HRDivision      00000   yes

30000   TaxDivision     00000   yes

10001   SalesTeam1      10000   no

10002   SalesTeam2      10000   no

20001   HrTeam1         20000   no

20002   HrTeam2         20000   no

30001   TaxTeam1        30000   no

30002   TaxTeam2        30000   no
```

When I want to create hierarchy in SSAS by giving atribute: id and description it gives me en error "Attribute relationships dont exist between one or more levels of this hierarchy". Do you have any idea how to build this hierarchy based on table like the one in example. I'd like to mention that is not 3-levels tree. There is about 5 levels.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From this type of source table, you would build a [parent child hierarchy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174846%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in Analysis Services.